# Safari javascript object not updating

Tags: javascript, object, safari

I have a piece of code that is working on all browsers except safari.

Basically I have an object called record.
record has properties, UserPhone, UserFax ...etc.
I also have a form with the same field names.
I update the object on the text field blur

```
$(this).on('blur', function() {
    console.log($(this).val()); // shows the new value correctly
    console.log($(this).attr('name')); // shows the right name correctly
    record[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    console.log(record); // shows the record with the old value, should show the new value
    updateDB();
});
```

The comments in the code to show what I'm getting in the console.
This code is working in other browsers.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(this).on('blur', function() {
    console.log($(this).val()); // shows the new value correctly
    console.log($(this).attr('name')); // shows the right name correctly
    var key = $(this).attr('name'),
        val = $(this).val();
    record[key] = val;
    console.log(record); // shows the record with the old value, should show the new value
    updateDB();
});
```

There is an ambiguity in your scope, I assume.

Also, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9auh6/) resembles your code and I don't have any problems whatsoever.

**EDIT**: And [the fiddle that addresses your problems](http://jsfiddle.net/mVENa/). The takeaways from this should be to always avoid inline javascript and bind elements later.

Comment: Thanks Ashesh, but it didn't work for me. Your fiddle works on the same browser, but not my code. I have screen shots from Safari and Chrome showing the difference, but I don't know how to put images in this forum.

Comment: This the whole function, it fires onblur for text boxes and onchange for select boxes;

Comment: function UpdateRecord(elm) {
    var val = $(elm).val();
    var key = $(elm).attr('name');
    record[key] = val;
    console.log(record);
}

Comment: And here is one of the text boxes:

Comment: <input type="tel" id="ApproverFax" name="ApproverFax" style="width: 60%" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" title="xxx-xxx-xxxx" required="required" onblur="UpdateRecord(this)"/>

Comment: @iham I've added the fiddle in the edit of the answer. There's ambiguity when you add inline javascript and its not good practice either. In my fiddle I've removed that.